Issue with SparkSession in Pytest Fixture in Databricks
I'm working on a pytest framework in Databricks, and I have the following project structure:
Reusables
--DataOperations.py
Testcases
--conftest.py (contains a fixture     with autouse=True andcope session that initializes the Spark session)
Test_validation.py (a class that contains test methods)
Runner
A notebook that calls pytest using subprocess.
In my conftest.py, I have a fixture set to automatically provide a Spark session to my tests. However, when I use SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() in the fixture, I encounter the following error:
"Master URL not set."
This error occurs even though I'm running the tests in a Databricks environment, where the Spark session should be automatically managed by the platform.
I need to initialize and use the Spark session within the fixture without encountering this error. How can I correctly configure the Spark session for pytest in Databricks to avoid this issue?
